# Extracting numbers from sentences

Tags: regex, r, string, text-extraction

I need to extract some numbers from a text.  Text is

```
x <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet[245], consectetur adipiscing (325). Deinde prima illa, quae in congressu[232]. solemus: Quid tu, inquit, huc? Sequitur disserendi ratio cognitioque 295. naturae;"
```

The numbers to be extracted are 325 and 232.  These are inside  brackets and at the end of sentence.  Other numbers are excluded.  I tried `strsplit(text, "[A-Za-z]+")`, but is not getting what I needed.

Comment: I'm curious on the downvote here?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a `stringi` approach

```
x <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet[245], consectetur adipiscing (325). Deinde prima illa, quae in congressu[232]. solemus: Quid tu, inquit, huc? Sequitur disserendi ratio cognitioque 295. naturae; Claudii libidini, qui tum erat summo ne imperio, dederetur"

library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(x, "(?<=[\\[(])\\d+(?=[\\])][.?!])")

## [[1]]
## [1] "325" "232"
```

Comment: Curious, doesn't `qdap` have function for getting text between  brackets?  I though I was you use it a few times before.

Comment: Yeah it has `bracketXtract` but this regex is less general (forces digits between) thus more accurate.  And I'm becoming a big fan of the `stringi` package with fast, consistent results.

Answer (score 4):

Another one:

```
r <- gregexpr("[[(]\\d+[])](?=\\.)", text, perl = TRUE)
(m <- regmatches(text, r)[[1]])
# [1] "(325)" "[232]"

as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", m))
# [1] 325 232
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `strsplit`....

```
> x <- 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet[245], consectetur adipiscing (325). Deinde prima illa, quae in congressu[232]. solemus: Quid tu, inquit, huc? Sequitur disserendi ratio cognitioque 295. naturae;'
> strsplit(x, '[^0-9]+')[[1]][3:4]
## [1] "325" "232"
```

Or using base R to extract these values.

```
> regmatches(x, gregexpr('[[(]\\K\\d+(?=[])](?!,))', x, perl=T))[[1]]
## [1] "325" "232"
```

Answer (score 0):

With re module

```
import re

string="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet[245], consectetur adipiscing (325). Deinde prima illa, quae in congressu[232]. solemus: Quid tu, inquit, huc? Sequitur disserendi ratio cognitioque 295. naturae;"

print string

pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=[\[(])\d+(?=[\])]\.)')

result = pattern.findall(string)

print result
```